# Implement search bar/button with dojo/html/css?

Tags: html, css, search, dojo

I'm trying to style my search bar to be more modern looking. Currently my search looks like:
[image]

which I get using the following HTML:

```
            <div id="search">
            <input type="text" id="parcel" size="30" value="Enter Parcel ID or Address"/>
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props='onClick:function(){ doFind();}'>Search</button>
        </div>
```

and CSS:

```
            #search {
            position:relative;
            top:2px !important;
            right: 95px;
            color:white !important;
            font-family:Goudy Old Style Italics;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:11pt;
        }
```

I would like to modify the search bar to look like the pic below, so that when the user clicks on the icon, the search is performed. I've tried implementing a few solutions found on google but I think something is stepping on my CSS. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could allow modern browsers handle the rendering of search inputs with input type="search."

Example and Tutorial: 
http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/5-search.html 
http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-search

W3C specification:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html